# Regex : Its possible to do submatching in regex?

Tags: regex, parsing, regex-group

I create this regex to parse mongodb url as follow:

/mongodb://((?'username'\w+):(?'password'\w+)@)?(?'hosts'\w[,\w]*)(/(?'defaultdb'[\w.]+))?(\?(?'options'.*$))?$/m

I do some tests in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bLQQVc/1) with it, and I wanna to know if its possible to parse the ',' (commas) in hosts group to result in an array, and similarly do this in options group with '&' separator.

My intentions is iterate by the regex result and use the matches groups with your result in one way, without need to split by separator.

Expected example:

mongodb://user:password@host,host2,host3,host4/databasename?options=1&options=2

group user: user

group password: password

group hosts: host

group hosts: host2

group hosts: host3

group hosts: host4

group defaultdb: databasename

group options: options=1

group options: options=2

Comment: It's probably more straightforward to split on the comma in code rather than attempting to do so with the regex.

Comment: @nickb I do. But, I wanna know if it's possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible work around to have all your data in the right order:

```js
let str = 'mongodb://user:password@host,host2,host3,host4/databasename?options=1&options=2'
// substring(10) to avoid 'mongodb://'
console.log(str.substring(10).split(/[:@,/&?]/))
```

---

**Edit**: I see before your edit that you are on Node, so an other solution is:

```
let str = 'mongodb://user:password@host,host2,host3,host4/databasename?options=1&options=2'

let regex = /mongodb:\/\/(?<username>\w+):(?<password>\w+)@(?<hosts>[,\w]*)\/(?<defaultdb>[\w\.]+)?\?(?<options>.*$)?$/

function splitGroup(group, items)
{
  items.forEach(function (item, index) {
    res.groups[group+'_'+index] = item
  });
}

res = regex.exec(str)

res.groups.hosts = res.groups.hosts.split(',')
res.groups.options = res.groups.options.split('&')

splitGroup('host', res.groups.hosts)
splitGroup('option', res.groups.options)

delete res.groups.hosts
delete res.groups.options

console.log(Object.keys(res.groups).filter(v => v.startsWith('host')))
// [ 'host_0', 'host_1', 'host_2', 'host_3' ]
console.log(Object.keys(res.groups).filter(v => v.startsWith('option')))
// [ 'option_0', 'option_1' ]
```

Comment: Huuummm... Nice, but I cant know what is what.

Comment: @DanielARF, If you have in your final result group like this: `host_0`, `host_1`... etc it's okay for you ?

Comment: Your solution is correct, and It's what I expect. But my question is only the possibility to do this only with regex.

Comment: @DanielARF, I think that is not possible because in javascript, an object can't have the same key twice, which will be the case if you have many `host` with different value. But maybe a workaround exist

Comment: I will consider your response. Thanks

Comment: @DanielARF, small precision, it can't be possible because *"A subpattern name must be unique"* but just with capturing group, it will be possible, but in this case, the solution with split is better